# Converting PDF to PNG with ImageMagick & Wand via Python

Tags: python, imagemagick-convert, wand

I am using ImageMagick to convert a PDF into an image.. it works great when I try:
`convert -density 150 -trim summary-reports/20211027 -quality 100 -flatten -sharpen 0x1.0  output/20211027.png`

So as far as I can tell, GS is working.

I am trying to do this with a script:

```
import os
from os.path import exists
from wand.image import Image
from wand.color import Color

filein = "summary-reports/20211027"
fileout = "output/20211027.png"

with Image(filename=f"{filein}", resolution=150) as img:
            format = "PNG"
            img.compression_quality = 150
            img.save(filename=fileout)
```

but it's resulting in an error:

```
wand.exceptions.WandRuntimeError: MagickReadImage returns false, but did not raise ImageMagick  exception. This can occur when a delegate is missing, or returns EXIT_SUCCESS without generating a raster.
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this worked...

```
import os
from os.path import exists
from wand.image import Image
from wand.color import Color

filein = "summary-reports/20211027"
fileout = "output/20211027.png"

with Image(filename=f"{filein}[0]", resolution=150) as img:
            format = "PNG"
            img.save(filename=fileout)
```

Not sure what happened.